# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Mrc'

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an error for the following code.
Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?
p.s. I have given the path correctly for.mrcfile

```
import numpy
import Mrc
a = Mrc.bindFile('somefile.mrc')
# a is a NumPy array with the image data memory mapped from
# somefile.mrc.  You can use it directly with any function
# that will take a NumPy array.
hist = numpy.histogram(a, bins=200)
# a.Mrc is an instances of the Mrc class.  One thing
# you can do with that class is print out key information from the header.
a.Mrc.info()
# Use a.Mrc.hdr to access the MRC header fields.
wavelength0_nm = a.Mrc.hdr.wave[0]
```

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in ()
>             3 a = Mrc.bindFile('/home/smitha/deep-image-prior/data/Falcon_2015_05_14-20_42_18.mrc')
>             4 hist = numpy.histogram(a, bins=200)
>       ----> 5 a.Mrc.info()
>             6 wavelength0_nm = a.Mrc.hdr.wave[0]
>             7
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Mrc'

Comment: When you write `a.Mrc.info()` after `a = Mrc.bindFile ...` you effectively say `Mrc.bindFile.Mrc.info()`. I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: try checking what is the type of `a`. `print(type(a))`

Comment: Well , I also tried  with Mrc.bindFile.Mrc.info(). But I am getting AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Mrc'
as an error

Comment: Yeah also tried with a. print(type(a)), now I am getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print' as an error.

Comment: How did you create the Mrc file?

Comment: Well, it's a .mrc format of cryoem dataset.